# Google Analytics Campaign Measurement - confused on the process

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

I've been reading up all day on Google Analytics Campaign Measurement for my Android app. I'm really confused on how this whole process works and it would be amazing if someone would help clear up some questions.

I've got the trackers set up in one of the activities:

```
@Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this);
  }
```

I ran a test campaign via the terminal as per the documentation:

```
$ ./adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER
-n your.package.name/path.to.receiver --es "referrer"
"utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&
utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"
```

I got the test to show up in LogCat

```
Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Campaign found: utm_source=testSource
```

**Questions:**

1. How do I use this with real campaigns? Where do the urls come from and do I have to manage them somehow or does Google take care of that?
2. How can I view these on my Analytics dashboard? I can't find anything about campaigns or anything.
3. If the only thing I'm tracking is where downloads are coming from, do I only need to put the code in the first activity of the app? Or every activity like the documentation says?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Because in linux terminal &(ampersand) is escaped that is the reason not work

Follow below given steps:-

1) Type **adb shell** and press enter

2) Then paste this

```
 am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.futureprints.smiley/com.futureprints.smiley.CustomCampaignTrackingReceiver --es "referrer" "utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"
```

3) Now check you will receive complete string in receiver

```
"utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"
```

Comment: its working for me check it again because in linux terminal &(ampersand) is escaped that is the reason not work so try it it will work for me

Comment: Actually it is working perfectly during testing.But in live app,Play store app broadcast sends only utm_source.The other parameters like utm_medium,utm_campaign etcare not shown in analytics dashboard(other are displayed as "(not set)").Does anybody come across this situation?

Answer (score 1):

1. To use it with real campaigns the easiest way is probably to use the Google Play URL builder. See here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns#google-play-url-builder
2. To view on the analytics dashboard go to "Acquisitions -> Google Play -> Sources"
3. If you only want to see where installs are coming from make sure you set up your INSTALL_REFERRER see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns. This goes in your manifest. Looking at your example it appears you have already done this. You shouldn't need to do anything else.

Comment: But what do I do with the URLs I create?

Comment: You probably have links to download you app, so lets say that you have a link in your website to download the app, instead of using the following href https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package nams>
You would use the url that you got, for example:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package nams>&referrer=utm_source%3D<source>%26utm_content%3D<content>...